# Git merge conflict, but there is no visible difference

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I often get conflicts when merging branches that look like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    private readonly IAdminService _adminService;

=======
    private readonly IAdminService _adminService;

>>>>>>> refs/remotes/origin/master
```

There is no visible difference. What would cause github to view this as a conflict?

Comment: Linefeeds is the keyword here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is invoked by white spaces character, such as tab, space. you can set you editor to show these characters.Also `git diff` provides options to ignore those character.

> --ignore-space-at-eol
>
> Ignore changes in whitespace at EOL.
>
> -b
>
> --ignore-space-change
>
> Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at
>   line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace 
>   characters to be equivalent.
>
> -w
>
> --ignore-all-space
>
> Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even > if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.